# Move the camera along its LookAt axis in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js, so if this is obvious then apologies upfront.

I set my camera using the LookAt method, and would like to move along that vector when pressing a key on the keyboard.

I've tried mimicking the feature by subtracting the camera vector from the point I'm looking at via `subVector`, normalized the resulting vector, then did something along the lines of:

```
camera.position.x += lookAtVector.x
camera.position.y += lookAtVector.y
camera.position.z += lookAtVector.z
```

...but I appear to be drifting a bit and not moving toward the lookAt point when I do this.  How can I move along a lookAt vector in three.js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The camera is looking down it's *negative-Z axis*, so you want to do this:

```
camera.translateZ( - distance );
```

three.js r.57

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't know I could do that with translateZ.  I guess the translate(X|Y|Z) methods work in object space, whereas something like camera.position.(x|y|z) is in world space?