# Camera configuration in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I'm totally new in ThreeJS and I'm trying to build my web application with it. I'm faced to a problem with the camera configuration.

I've got one perspective camera that be able to look and move at every point of my scene.

The problem is that I just want to my camera can look at every point (left, right, up and down). But, I don't want that it can move at every point (what I mean is the difference between move and look, not the same behavior). I want that it just can move on the Z axis (depth).

Here, my camera :

```
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you need

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15661803/507186

```
camera.translateZ( - distance );
```

It will translate without changing the LookAt position

Answer (score 0):

First a small explanation of the configuration of the camera

```
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
```

**PerspectiveCamera**( fov, aspect, near, far );

- **fov** — Camera frustum vertical field of view.
- **aspect** — Camera frustum aspect ratio.(Width/Height)
- **near** — Camera frustum near plane.
- **far** — Camera frustum far plane.

This configures the camera, but it does not control its movements or where it sees.

To control where the camera is looking, use the following code:

```
this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)); // x, y, z
```

But if you use some library to control the camera (OrbitControls.js), you may have to use:

```
this.controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 ); //x, y, z
```

If you do not use any library for the control of the camera then you should have no problem with the "**lookAt()**".

And to keep the camera in a fixed position, use the following code:

```
this.camera.position.x      =   0;
this.camera.position.z      =   0;
this.camera.position.y      =   0;
```

Ahora lo que realmente desea es administrar la profundidad de la cámara que tendrá que utilizar el siguiente código:

```
this.fov = 0;
this.camera.projectionMatrix.makePerspective(this.fov,  window.innerWidth   /   window.innerHeight, this.near,  this.far));
```

> Be careful with this, so as not to leave the field of vision controlled by the near and far.

For more information see [threejs.org](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/Camera)